# Certain links refuse to open in new tab using google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

Particularly on the letgo.com website. I have a relatively high number of items for sale on there and when you go to your profile page to view your listings it only shows a max of 20 items per page then you have to scroll to bottom and hit "load more". This is extremely slow when you want to get to the bottom of your postings and you have 250-300 active posts and every time you click a link then go back it refreshes to first page only.

My solution was to just scroll to bottom once and leave the tab open so I could open each item in a new tab to prevent the page from refreshing. A month or so ago Letgo updated their website and now the links to open each post refuse to open in new tabs. I can't CMD click them and there's no option in the right click menu to open in new tab. Anyone know of a workaround for this or a way to force chrome to open link in new tab? I used a CSS selector and found the links are h3 links if that helps. Using chrome browser on a macbook. It's almost as if chrome doesn't recognize them as links but they function like links?

Edit: This is what I get when I right click one of the links: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzVuv.jpg

Comment: Perhaps theres a way to right click the link, copy the URL,and open a new tab using that link?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't. I added an imgur link to show the right click menu options I have.

Comment: Hmm, it seems its no longer a hyperlink, yet when clicked it redirects you to the product page. I think there may be some sort of JavaScript performing this function - there must be a link somewhere in the source, so perhaps there is a type of automation script to search patterns for the products, and then find the enbedded link and open them up? I can not help any more as I have no experience in this field but I think that this is possible using some sort of live web scripting perhaps...